# How to detect touch on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, touch

On UIWebview, how can I detect a touch?

But not when user clicks some URL or touching a control.

Is it possible to handle it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:

Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in declaration file (i.e. your .h file)

Step 1: Just set the delegate of gestureRecognizer: (in .m file viewDidLoad)

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *webViewTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
webViewTapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
webViewTapped.delegate = self;
[offScreenWebView addGestureRecognizer:webViewTapped];
[webViewTapped release];
```

Step 2: Override this function: (in .m file)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Step 3: Now implement the tapAction function:

```
- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{    
    NSLog(@"touched");

    // Get the specific point that was touched
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is great if you only need to detect taps. If you need to detect all touches, the best way is to create a new UIView subclass and place it over the webview. In the subclass you can detect touches using hitTest:

TouchOverlay.h

```
@class TouchOverlay;

@protocol TouchOverlayDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)touchOverlayTouched:(TV4TouchOverlay *)touchOverlay;

@end


@interface TouchOverlay : UIView
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <TouchOverlayDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Touchoverlay.m

```
@implementation TouchOverlay

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  return self;
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
  if (hitView == self) {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(touchOverlayTouched:)]) {
      [self.delegate touchOverlayTouched:self];
    }
    return nil;     // Tell the OS to keep looking for a responder
  }
  return hitView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the accepted answer above will only capture *tap* gestures (touchDown and touchUp without a drag in between), and that swipe gestures will be ignored.

For my purposes I needed to be informed of both, and so I added swipe gesture recognizers appropriately.  (Note that despite being a bit field, you can't `OR` together swipe gesture recognizers' `direction` property, so 4 gesture recognizers are required to detect any swipe).

```
// Note that despite being a bit field, you can't `OR` together swipe gesture
// recognizers' `direction` property, so 4 gesture recognizers are required
// to detect any swipe
for (NSNumber * swipeDirection in @[@(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp), @(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown), @(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft), @(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)]) {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(timerReset:)];
    swipe.direction = [swipeDirection integerValue];
    swipe.delegate = self;
    [rootWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything that inherits from UIResponder can handle touches (so does UIWebView). Read the doc:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You'll have to use:

```
touchesBegan:withEvent:
```

**Edit:** Adding the comment here for clarity-

I believe then there's no clean way of doing it, you can either override the hittest withEvent method like [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17121-fyi-how-pass-touch-events-uiwebview.html)  or do a hack like this: [overriding UIView](https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/blob/4028ab78af92ab17465338575b78ed80310a613f/WebViewTappingHack/Classes/PSWebView.m)

Comment: I'm aware of it. But when i sub classed uiwebview and implemented touchesBegan and touchesEnded, they are not being called at all.....

Comment: In that case, you can create a transparent UIView over the webview and use touches method on it.

Comment: If I place transparent UIView over it, it will loose default functionality of webview to click links or touch the controls etc..... am i right?

Comment: I believe then there's no clean way of doing it, you can either override the hittest withEvent method like this http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17121-fyi-how-pass-touch-events-uiwebview.html  or do a hack like this https://github.com/psychs/iphone-samples/blob/4028ab78af92ab17465338575b78ed80310a613f/WebViewTappingHack/Classes/PSWebView.m

Comment: Thanks, i'll surely have a look at it. Are you from bangalore, India? can I have your contact details..... to discuss more

Comment: I hope the links I mentione help you. Also, I live in Delhi, but I am sorry I cannot publicly post my contact details and I couldn't find a way to send a private message to you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want to override the options that popup when they hold down on a link? I managed to get one to work with this tutorial/guide but the one posted here is still slightly buggy and needs you to do some fine tuning:
http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/

Comment: No. I've a close button on web view. when user touches the web view, i want to hide it. when touched again, it will show the close button again. but i'm not able to detect touches on web view.

Comment: You could modify that tutorial to detect the type of touch you want to monitor, rather then the tap and hold action it is looking for in the example.