# iOS Swift UIWebView Link Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I need to get the coordinates of a link tapped on in a UIWebView.  I tried using TapGestureRecognizer but it doesn't trigger when the link is tapped.  I thought I might be able to get the coordinates from Javascript via stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and I couldn't get that to work either.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How can a _link_ have "coordinates"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Swift equivalent of this answer: [How to detect touch on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878821/2108547).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    let myWebView = UIWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myWebView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
        myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!))

        let webViewTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapAction:")
        webViewTapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        webViewTapped.delegate = self
        myWebView.addGestureRecognizer(webViewTapped)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tapAction(sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        println(point.x)
        println(point.y)
    }
```

Comment: That is PRECISELY what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UIView hitTest might be of use.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event ;
```

Overriding it (or using a category) in your web view might allow you to process tap coordinates of the web view's contained items which wouldn't be passed to the superview by a gesture recognizer